# How to identify the popup authentication scheme used in an URL?

Tags: java, authentication, popup

I'm trying to extract information from an URL using my Java code. But the URL has a pop-up authentication scheme. How would I know the authentication scheme used? I have the credentials for it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the authentication is based on HTTP. There are several techniques to use (HTTP basic authentication Kerberos NTLM and so on) Each of this technologies applies additional information into HTTP header. So the authentification is not URL based but HTTP Header based.

Please give us more information about your problem, to help you

Comment: that is Kerberos ... the "os" is not an abbreviation for Operating System, or anything else; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerberus

Comment: Thanks for yo info.. I need to build a java class to extract data on a https link which is protected by this popup authentication scheme.. Pls give me more info as I'm new to java.. I've learnt how to connect to a basic unprotected http link..

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html
there the basic authentication mechanism are described. if this guide is not enough we can work together on a solution

Answer (score 0):

A browser typically shows an authentication "popup" when the server responds to an HTTP request with a ["401 Unauthorized" response message](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2).  The response header includes a ["WWW-Authentication" header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.47) which tells you the authentication scheme to use (among other things).

There are various ways to deal with this in a Java application, depending on how you are attempting to fetch the web resource associated with the URL.  For instance, if you are using `HttpUrlConnection`, you can extract the "WWW-Authentication" header, parse it, and extract the authentication scheme.